# Unable to host chefserver on UI

Tags: docker, chef-infra, devops

## Used below commands to dockerize chefserver

a)

```
docker run -ti --name chef-data sappho/chef-server date -R
```

b)

```
docker run -ti --name chef --hostname chef.example.com --privileged \
    --volumes-from chef-data -p 443:443 \
    -d --restart always sappho/chef-server
```

c)

```
docker exec -ti chef chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

d)

```
docker stop chef
```

e)

## docker start chef

Ref : https://github.com/sappho/docker-build-chef-server

I am unable to ckeck via UI like localhost:443 on web...How i can access on web..Any pointers?

Comment: What is the actual issue you are experiencing? You've only said that you are "unable to check vi UI like localhost:443", but did not include any error message. Is your Docker engine running on localhost? If it is in a VM then it would be in the localhost of that VM. Is it a "connection refused" ? If so, then check whether the container is still running. Show logs from the container. Is it another error other than connection refused? if so, what is it?

Comment: Yes....Connection refused! both on VM and on local. https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker/playground ---> Same here also connection refused and when i append 443 on display port....it throws...Connecting to Port 443
We're currently trying to connect to a HTTP service running on 443. Services can sometimes take a few moments to start, even upto five minutes.